# RestSharp returns no response

Tags: c#, .net-core, restsharp

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 project using RestSharp (v107.3.0).

Sometimes, I don't how the frequency, luckily it's not often, the library returns a null response and a 0 response status code whatever the API sends.

Here is my code :

```
private async Task<T> CallApi<T>(myConfig config,
    string suffixUrl,
    Method method,
    HttpStatusCode[] expectedResponses,
    string bodyParameter = null)
{
    Uri requestUrl = null;
    string responseContent = null;

    try
    {
        using (var client = new RestClient(_restClientOptions))
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(suffixUrl, method);
            request.Timeout = 15000;
            request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Basic {config.Auth}");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

            if (bodyParameter != null)
            {
                request.AddStringBody(bodyParameter, DataFormat.Json);
            }

            requestUrl = client.BuildUri(request);

            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

            // ->>>>>>> Sometimes response.Content equals null and response.statusCode = 0
            responseContent = response.Content;

            foreach (var expectedResponse in expectedResponses)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == expectedResponse)
                {
                    switch (expectedResponse)
                    {
                        default:
                            Logger.LogInformation("reponse :{0}", responseContent);
                            var obj = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
                            return obj.ToObject<T>();
                    }
                }
            }

            Logger.LogWarning("Réponse innatendue lors d'un apel a l'api, Url={requestUrl}, BodyParameter={bodyParameter}, StatusCode={statusCode}, Reponse={Content}",
            requestUrl, bodyParameter, response.StatusCode, responseContent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //catch errors
        Logger.LogError(ex, "Erreur lors d'un apel a l'api, url={requestUrl}, BodyParameter={bodyParameter}, responseContent={responseContent}",
                requestUrl, bodyParameter, responseContent);
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Does somebody else already have a solution for this problem?
Is there a problem with my code ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a HttpStatusCode of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795818/getting-a-httpstatuscode-of-0)

Comment: @Orace I don't think so.
Although I received 0, I know that my request was processed succesfully by the API server and therefore I imagine that it returned a response with status code 200 and content

Comment: A zero (0) response code is usually caused by an inability to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will not be the perfect answer for the next readers but in my case, I decided to remove Restsharp library and doing calls with HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RestSharp, Method.Get request make sure you don't set Header **"Content-Type": "application/json"**. Because RestSharp complained about Method.Get request cannot have any content in its request. Also, try set **ThrowOnAnyError = true** to see a more detailed error if there is any.

```
// Init Rest Client
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://local.xyz")
{
    MaxTimeout = -1,
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
    ThrowOnAnyError = true
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```